# when displaying records its duplicating on page refresh?

Tags: php, mysql

my code looks like this

when I refresh the page it's duplicating the last value how to avoid this problem.  This is the quoa.php code! I have tried adding distinct but its working fine but there is no use problem still on there?

**phpcode**

```
<?php  
/* connection inclution code will be here */
include 'connection/conn.php';

//defining the variables to the text fields 
$question = $_POST['qst'];  
$questionext = $_POST['qsttextarea'];

//validating the text fields , if there is no text show the msg after else 
if(isset($_POST['qst']) && isset($_POST['qsttextarea'])) 
{


} else {

    $pleasefill = "please fill all the fields";
}

//sending data to the database 
$mysqlinsert = "INSERT INTO questions(qsttable,qstext) VALUES ('$question','$questionext')";

//header("Location: success.php");
if (!mysqli_query($connection,$mysqlinsert)) {
    echo " record not inserted";
} else {
 $submited = (" &nbsp;&nbsp; your question is submited please wait for the response");
}

//getting data from the database
if ($data = mysqli_query($connection,"select distinct * from questions")); {

} 
?>
```

**show record code**

```
<?php
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($data)) {
        echo '
        <div id="question_div">  <span class="fa fa-chevron-right" id="spantick"></span> &nbsp;'.'<a href="#" id="qsttable">'.$row['qsttable'].'</a> <br />'.'<p id="qstext">'.$row['qstext'].' </p> </div> ' ;


    }echo '<a href="question.php?id='.$row['qid'].'"> Read more  </a>';

    ?>
```

Comment: after inserting you should header redirect to the show record page..

Answer (score 0):

You should perform html validation in your input fields ,in that way when you refresh the page all the fields will be empty and previous values will not be stored.
Just add 'required' keyword in your fields ,that will do.
eg.

Comment: I used the code it's working fine when I click the form submitting button . but when i refresh the page its still like that ?

Comment: yes it will work fine when you submit it because when you submit the values will go to the form action page,but that's not the case when you refresh the page . If you want to refresh all the values then you have to apply some validation . So please edit your code according to my answer ,i hope it will work :)

Comment: I think PHP validation will work for the page properly or sql prevent . do you have any tutorial. that will be a good help ! thanks Ayush

Comment: php validation or sql validation will work only when you click the submit button or when you the reach the form action page until then it will not work.

Comment: atleast give a try to html validation if it doesnt work then you can go for php validation or jquery validation